# Infinite Loop Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm having trouble with the code below using vue it cause the website to print multiple "test" / infinite loop but it should only print 2 times.

Any suggestions on the problem? by the way I'm kindly new with vue so please bear with me.

Javascript File

```
var rs = [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "xxxx",
     "description": "Description",
     "address": "vvvvv",
     "image": "img-src"
 },
 {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "yyyyyy",
     "description": "Description",
     "address": "qqqqqqqq",
     "image": "img-src"
 } ];

 var restaurant_list = new Vue({
     el: '#restaurant_list',
     data: {
       restaurants: rs
     } 
 })
```

HTML File

```
<div class="container" id="restaurant_list">
    <div v-for="restaurant in restaurants">
        <label>test</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i guess vue isn´t defined. Did you include the script? Maybe this will help you https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: that does not happen when I reproduced your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2m06hn4/1/). Can you reproduce the problem with complete code if there is more?

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> is defined in my html file its weird if I do something like this below its working                                                                                                 var restaurant_list = new Vue({
    el: '#restaurant_list',
    data: {
        services: [1,2]
    }
})

Comment: didnt get any problem with your code  http://jsfiddle.net/channasmcs/hadfc07q/2/embedded/js,html,css,result/dark/

Comment: Nothing in your code can gives a infinity loop